# Custom input field on Woocommerce Single Product Page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm hopping someone can help me figure out how to add a custom text field to my single woocommerce product page.

I simply want to add a form and found this plugin, but it's not customizable. I much rather create the form and place it where I need it. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-fields-factory/

Thanks!

Comment: There are many tutorials about this, here's [mine](https://www.kathyisawesome.com/add-a-custom-field-to-woocommerce-product/)

Comment: @helgatheviking Thank you for the reply and will go over your tutorial. However I noticed that you mentioned "Product Add-Ons" which I looked at but wasn't sure if it was customizable. Do yo happen to know if it is? As in terms of design?

Comment: What part do you need to customize?

Comment: Well I added your script and created the fields but I need to somehow put them outside the form for it to work with my design. Is that possible?

Comment: If you put them outside the form, how do you expect to submit the values as part of the form?

Comment: True, we decided to update our design, but your tutorial worked and helped me achieve what I needed, so thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

You Can try This, This will work 100%,

```
// Display Fields (function.php)

function woo_add_custom_general_fields() {

  global $woocommerce, $post;

  echo '<div class="options_group">';

  // Custom fields will be created here...

  echo '</div>';

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields' );
```

To create a text field type, you will need to use that code:

```
// Text Field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array( 
        'id'          => '_text_field', 
        'label'       => __( 'My Text Field', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => 'http://',
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
);
```

To create a textarea, here is the code to use:

```
// Textarea
woocommerce_wp_textarea_input( 
    array( 
        'id'          => '_textarea', 
        'label'       => __( 'My Textarea', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'placeholder' => '', 
        'description' => __( 'Enter the custom value here.', 'woocommerce' ) 
    )
);
```

Saving Fields Values:

```
function woo_add_custom_general_fields_save( $post_id ){

    // Text Field
    $woocommerce_text_field = $_POST['_text_field'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_text_field ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_text_field', esc_attr( $woocommerce_text_field ) );


    // Textarea
    $woocommerce_textarea = $_POST['_textarea'];
    if( !empty( $woocommerce_textarea ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_textarea', esc_html( $woocommerce_textarea ) );   
}
// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woo_add_custom_general_fields_save' );
```

[image]

Display Custom Field Value

```
<?php
// Display Custom Field Value
echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'my-field-slug', true );
// You can also use
echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'my-field-slug', true );
?>
```

to know more you can visit :
http://www.remicorson.com/mastering-woocommerce-products-custom-fields/

Comment: Would this allow my customers to enter data? It sounds like it's all in the backend